# Assembler failed link obj file MASM32

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I am a Chinese who interested in computer science.
I am learning assembly language following **Assembly Language FOR x86 PROCESSORS Seventh Edition** by Kip Irvine.

I download MASM32 and try coding in MASM32 Editor


code below:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO,dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
byteVal BYTE 10h
.code
main PROC
    mov esi,OFFSET byteVal
    mov al,[esi]
    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

When I Assemble ASM file it works and generate .obj file. But, when I Run 'Assemble and Link' I got link errors.

```
xxxx.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess@4
xxxx.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Can anyone help me solve this & explain why?

Comment: Presumably you're not linking against kernel32.lib. Replace the `ExitProcess PROTO` line with `include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc ` and `includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib`

Comment: @Michael It does wok. Since I include the kernel32.inc file why I have to include the lib file kernel32.lib? Is there any connections between kernel32.inc and kernel32.lib?

Comment: @Kengyen - kernel.inc is a text (source) file, if you look at it with an editor, does it have an includelib directive in it? If not, then you'll need to have an includelib in your source code as commented by Michael.

Comment: @Kengyen: The inc files just contain function prototypes and related constants. The lib files contain the actual object code for those functions (if it's a static library), or a reference telling the linker which DLL to import the function from (if it's a dynamic library).

Comment: Thank you @Michael